# Ruby on Rails difference between cookies[:remember_token] and cookies["remember_token"]

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have trouble undestanding the following situation:

I am logging in and remembering my users by doing the following

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    user=User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      log_in(user)
      params[:session][:remember_me]=="1" ? remember(user) : forget(user)
      redirect_to user
    else
      flash.now[:danger]="Invalid email/password combination"
      render "new"
    end
  end
```

and

```
module SessionsHelper

    def remember(user)
        user.remember
        cookies.permanent.signed[:user_id]=user.id
        cookies.permanent[:remember_token]=user.remember_token
    end
```

all of which works fine. The thing that I don't understand though, is that in an integration test I have to use cookies["remember_token"] because in the following situation cookies[:remember_token] will return nil

```
test "login with remember_me" do
    log_in_as(@user)
    assert_not_nil cookies["remember_token"]
end
```

Why does it return nil here and why does it not do that, if I use it for example as a parameter in a function inside of the Sessionhelper ( for example user.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token]) )

P.S.: All of the code above comes from the Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl https://www.railstutorial.org/book (chap. 9.3.1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because in normal application `cookies` method returns `ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieJar` object which always converts cookie names to string. In integration test, `cookies` method returns `Rack::Test::CookieJar` object which doesn't do such conversion. So if you set your cookie in tests via symbol you need to access it via symbol. The same goes if you set your cookie via string.

Comment: Any thoughts on why HashWithIndifferentAccess isn't used internally to represent the cookies in CookieJar class? I found the source where it does `@cookies[name.to_s]`.

Comment: I can think of many reasons. This class is quite heavy and allows nested hashes which also act as HWIA.  This is not that common with cookies. Maybe performance reasons also, like number of object allocations.

Comment: yeah. I went and look at the ActiveSupport version and the implementation is considerably more complex than I'd expected when thinking about what the class actually provides.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's because there is everything an object in ruby.
So if the hash table has the object *:remember_token* as the key and you are asking for the key *remember_token* those two are simply two different objects.